# mysql find latest records smaller than today

Tags: mysql

Please help a MySQL newbie:

I have 2 tables:

```
assets

asset_id |  description
------------------------
001      |  Crate of Laptops
002      |  Crate of OhBots
003      |  Crate of Spheros


bookings

id       | asset_id   |  start_date     |     end_date   |   location
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 001        |    2018/10/01   |   2018/10/10   |   Barnet
2        | 001        |    2018/10/12   |   2018/10/15   |   Hendon
3        | 002        |    2018/10/01   |   2018/10/10   |   Finchley
4        | 001        |    2018/12/01   |   2018/12/04   |   Brent
```

I need to show all of the latest bookings for each asset with a start date smaller than today - so if the date today is 2018/10/19 it should give me details for booking ids:

```
asset_id     |       location
------------------------------
001          |       Hendon
002          |       Finchley
```

So far I have this, but it doesnt show the latest booking - it shows all of them. I think I need a sub query using MAX() but cannot get that to work. There are  a number of posts on how to get the latest values from a table, but I also need start_date to be in the past.

```
SELECT asset.asset_id, asset.description, booking.location, booking.start_date
FROM  assets AS asset
INNER JOIN bookings AS booking 
ON asset.asset_id=booking.asset_id
WHERE booking.start_date <= NOW()
ORDER BY asset.asset_id DESC;
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you need to use `MAX()` to find the maximum start date for each asset in a subquery, and then you need to join that back to the `booking` table to find the other corresponding information.

```
SELECT a.id, a.description, b.start_date, b.location
FROM assets a
INNER JOIN bookings b ON (a.id = b.asset_id)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.asset_id, MAX(b.start_date) AS start_date
    FROM bookings b
    WHERE b.start_date < CURDATE()
    GROUP BY b.asset_id
) c ON (b.asset_id = c.asset_id AND b.start_date = c.start_date)
```

Here's a working database fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mci3TkZpZxKcJckWNVHrBK/0

Comment: That works very well! Now I need to find the assets from the asset table that are not in the query results - is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is that assets without a booking? Assets without a booking before today? What have you tried?

Comment: I need assets that do not appear in the results of the above query. I tried SELECT asset.asset_id, asset.description FROM assets as asset WHERE asset.asset_id NOT IN (Here I pasted the query from above) but I get an error saying Operand should contain 1 Column.

Comment: Change the query from above to return only the `asset_id`, and what you posted will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can order by from the start_date.
Try this,

```
SELECT asset.asset_id, asset.description, booking.location, booking.start_date
FROM  assets AS asset
INNER JOIN bookings AS booking 
ON asset.asset_id=booking.asset_id
WHERE booking.start_date <= NOW()
ORDER BY asset.asset_id,booking.start_date DESC;
```